# Sending Data to SalesForce by HttpClient(C#) Post Method, Not Working

Tags: c#, rest, salesforce, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to send a json Object to SalesFroce using HttpClient, but this behaves Weirdly...

First i login in to Salesforce Via following code

```
var sendPaylod = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
{"grant_type","password"},
{"client_id",s_clientId},
{"client_secret",s_clientSecrate},
{"username",s_username},
{"password",s_password}
};

HttpClient auth = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(sendPaylod);
HttpResponseMessage response = await auth.PostAsync(s_tokenRequestEndpointUrl, content);
string msg = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(msg);
string authToken = (String)jsonObj["access_token"];
```

Now I have got `authToken` as a bearer token to send data to salesFroce

I am doing that by Following

```
var obj = new { Director = "003e000001MQYjB", 
                CityName = "XXAA", 
                CityId = "000000",  
                RegionName = "India", 
                RegionId = "00000" };
 
string c_url = "URL to which data will sent";
var c_Obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
var c_content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(c_Obj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpClient c_client = new HttpClient();
c_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization","Bearer "+authToken);

HttpContent c_content = new StringContent(c_Obj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
c_content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var c_response = await c_client.PostAsync(c_url, content);
var c_msg = await c_response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Now Am getting Following Response...

> 

```
"status": "success",
"recordId": "",
"message": ""
```

> 

If i Use Same Bearer Token in Postman and Send same Json Object I receive Following response.

> 

```
"status": "success",
"recordId": "a16e0000002qV6aE",
"message": ""
```

> 

Please Help in this matter.

Comment: try this: c_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

Comment: I tried it, Doesn't work.. Program didn't executes further after this line... and execution will freeze there... and i also can't get what is issue here.

Comment: sorry I meant - c_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken ); –

Comment: Just Tried it, Same Result.

Comment: var c_response = await c_client.PostAsync(c_url, content); change to c_client.PostAsync(c_url, c_content);

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare header in first request between c# and fiddler.  Then make c# header looks like fiddler.  The default headers in c# are different than fiddler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the next errors:

Change:

```
var c_response = await c_client.PostAsync(c_url, content);
```

to:

```
var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
c_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
var c_response = await c_client.PostAsync(c_url, c_content); 
var c_msg = await c_response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<your return class>(c_msg);
```

and change your authorization to:

```
 c_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken );
```